# Tailwind margin and padding not applying

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a simple React component which renders this:

```
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="p-10 underline mx-10 text-3xl">Hello</h1>
    </div>
```

Here is what that produces. As you can see, the `underline` and `text-3xl` classes work, but the margin and padding ones are not applied.

[image: result]

[image: devtools]

Since some of the classes work, I don't think the config is the issue, but here it is (vite app)

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
};
```

Comment: `h1 { padding: 10px; margin: 0 10px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

For some reason, since I was using Vite, I needed to install PostCSS.

Added the package, along with a postcss file, restarted the app and it worked.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite